# Why is this data being stored as a string and not a float? (Python)

Tags: python, string, list

I am writing a simple Python program to store user inputted lap times in a list and then have a few functions performed on that list.

My problem is, despite explicitly declaring the lap times as 'float' before appending them into the list, they are still getting stored as strings. This means I cannot perform functions like sum() on the list as I am getting error messages such as: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'.

Here is the code:

```
lapTimes = []

count = 0

while True:
    count += 1
    lap = input("Enter lap time " + str(count) + ": ")

if lap == 'x':
    break

else:
    float(lap)
    print(type(lap))
    lapTimes.append(lap)


print(type(lapTimes[-1]))
print("Fastest Lap time was: ", min(lapTimes))
print("Slowest lap time was: ", max(lapTimes))
```

After declaring 'lap' as a float in the else clause, I have written written a line to print the data type of 'lap', and when run I get told it's a string!

I have done the same thing with the print(type(lapTimes[-1])) line just to make sure, and yep I still get told the data is a string.

There are supposed to be more lines of code on the bottom printing the sum of the list and the average lap time, which will not work because of this problem.

Comment: Please indent your code inside while loop.

Answer (score 2):

> My problem is, despite explicitly declaring the lap times as 'float'
>   before appending them into the list, they are still getting stored as
>   strings.

You have done no such thing. Python *doesn't have variable declarations*. You have simply called the `float` type constructor and passed it a string as an argument. It *returns* the `float` value you are expecting, but you never capture its output, and it is immediately discarded. Instead, do:

```
lapTimes.append(float(lap))
```

Comment: @user2357112 ugh thanks for fixing all those mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are not assigning the value of `float(lap)`. Write

```
lap=float(lap)
```

or better

```
lap = float(input("Enter lap time " + str(count) + ": "))
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check documentation about `float()`
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#float

The return value of `float()` is a float.

In else block, you need write codes like this:

```
else:
    lap = float(lap)
    print(type(lap))
    lapTimes.append(lap)
```

Comment: It's always good to cite documentation, but you should perhaps put the relevant part in the answer itself.

Answer (score 0):

you should write `lap = float(lap)`. Just writing `float(lap)` does nothing to the original lap variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
lapTimes = []

count = 0

while True:
    count += 1
    lap = input("Enter lap time " + str(count) + ": ")

    if lap == 'x':
        break

    else:
        lap = float(lap)
        print(type(lap))
        lapTimes.append(lap)


print(type(lapTimes[-1]))
print("Fastest Lap time was: ", min(lapTimes))
print("Slowest lap time was: ", max(lapTimes))
```

You missed assignment of lap after converting to float. That's why saw error.